# Import errors when trying to use pandas_gbq

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have been trying to run the code on [this](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/authentication.html) page which describes how to authenticate before using the pandas_gbq.read_gbq function:

```
import pandas_gbq
import pydata_google_auth

SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
]

credentials = pydata_google_auth.get_user_credentials(
    SCOPES,
    # Set auth_local_webserver to True to have a slightly more convienient
    # authorization flow. Note, this doesn't work if you're running from a
    # notebook on a remote sever, such as over SSH or with Google Colab.
    auth_local_webserver=True,)


df = pandas_gbq.read_gbq(
    "SELECT my_col FROM `my_dataset.my_table`",
    project_id='YOUR-PROJECT-ID',
    credentials=credentials,)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in _test_google_api_imports()
     94 
---> 95     try:
     96         from google.cloud import bigquery  # noqa

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/__init__.py in <module>
     34 
---> 35 from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client
     36 from google.cloud.bigquery.dataset import AccessEntry

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py in <module>
     52 from google.cloud.bigquery import _pandas_helpers
---> 53 from google.cloud.bigquery.dataset import Dataset
     54 from google.cloud.bigquery.dataset import DatasetListItem

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/dataset.py in <module>
     23 from google.cloud.bigquery import _helpers
---> 24 from google.cloud.bigquery.model import ModelReference
     25 from google.cloud.bigquery.routine import RoutineReference

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/model.py in <module>
     26 from google.cloud.bigquery import _helpers
---> 27 from google.cloud.bigquery_v2 import types
     28 

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_v2/__init__.py in <module>
     22 
---> 23 from google.cloud.bigquery_v2 import types
     24 from google.cloud.bigquery_v2.gapic import enums

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_v2/types.py in <module>
     22 
---> 23 from google.cloud.bigquery_v2.proto import model_pb2
     24 from google.cloud.bigquery_v2.proto import model_reference_pb2

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_v2/proto/model_pb2.py in <module>
     27 from google.api import annotations_pb2 as google_dot_api_dot_annotations__pb2
---> 28 from google.api import client_pb2 as google_dot_api_dot_client__pb2
     29 

ImportError: cannot import name 'client_pb2' from 'google.api' (/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api/__init__.py)
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling using the following command line code without any luck:

```
pip install pandas-gbq -U
```

This same code seems to work without any issue on my PC with Anaconda installed. However, the code does not run on my mac. Both computers have python 3.7 installed. I installed python 3 on my mac via homebrew, and I do not have Anaconda installed on that computer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem. but solve it by installing using conda:

```html
conda install pandas-gbq --channel conda-forge
```